# plot 2 lines timeseries with python seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have this dataframe:

```
DATE   FILETYPE FREQ
2015-05-08  tif 10
2015-09-30  pdf 17
2015-10-01  pdf 34
2015-10-02  JPG 67
2015-10-05  pdf 31
2015-10-06  TIF 13
```

........

and I'm trying to GET seaborn timeseries plotting a line per filetype, but to no avail.  **I get an error:  KeyError: 'FILETYPE'**

```
seaborn.tsplot(time="DATE", value="FREQ",condition="FILETYPE", data=dataframe)
plt.show()
```

**[update]**
Solved the previous error reindexing the dataframe, but now I get another error:  **index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1**

Comment: what does `dataframe.columns.tolist()` show?

Comment: dataframe.columns.tolist() :       ['FREQ']

Comment: that seems to indicate your df only has a single column?

Comment: seems to be. but solving this issue still don't get the plot. I did     df= dataframe.reset_index()   and now tolist()   gets    ['DATE', 'TYPE', 'FREQ']  but plot gives me an error :  index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: this indicates that date and type were originally your index, even if you didn't have those as your index FILETYPE was never a column